# How can I display a popover even when the button is not pressed yet?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter-bootstrap.
The code below enable the popover, and it appears when the user presses a button.

I want to display popover as default when the page is loaded. 
Is it possible?

```
<li>
    <a data-original-title="Popover on top" href="#" class="btn" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus." title="">Popover on top</a>
    <div style="top: -58px; left: 58.7083px; display: block;" class="popover fade top in">
        <div class="arrow"></div>
        <h3 class="popover-title">Popover on top</h3>
        <div class="popover-content">Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.</div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but why do you repeat the popover-content as both attribute *and* content in a div? (`.popover-content`) It is not nessecary.

```
<a data-original-title="Popover on top" id="popover-on-top" href="#" class="btn" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus." title="">Popover on top</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#popover-on-top").popover('toggle');
</script>
```

Yuo dont even need to put in a document ready()

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can call this JavaScript:

```
$('#element').popover('show');
```

See: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers